# simple react-pose opacity transition dont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-hooks, react-pose

i'm new with `react-pose` and i try a simple thing but the transition dont work.

I only want to have a transition between 2 states.

Like `opacity 0 => 1`

I want to use it with a const so i use the new react hook.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import posed from 'react-pose';

const Pop = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(false);
  const Box = posed.div({
    left: { x: 0 },
    right: { x: 100 }
  });
  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setPosition(!position);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box pose={position ? 'left' : 'right'} className="box" />
      <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>Toggle visibility</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pop;
```

Everything is working but this code act like i have set `transition: 0s`

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution
You need to put the const Box outside the react class, for prevent rerender.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import posed from 'react-pose';

const Box = posed.div({
    left: { x: 0 },
    right: { x: 100 }
  });

const Pop = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(false);
  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setPosition(!position);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box pose={position ? 'left' : 'right'} className="box" />
      <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>Toggle visibility</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pop;
```